# Creating buffer around points (layer + map in the same PCS)?

Tags: qgis, buffer

Currently creating a map of fire stations in LA and want to create a 50-mile buffer around them. My project right now is in NAD 27 / [EPSG:26799](https://epsg.io/26799) (Projected CS). I also managed to save my shapefile with all the points into the same PCS.

However, when I try to create a buffer around these points, I am still getting a huge thing that takes up the whole map. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How big is your map extent? Los Angeles itself is roughly 50 miles wide, so a 50 mile buffer of multiple points within LA would completely cover LA. (Keep in mind that a 50-mile buffer has a 50 mile *radius* and thus is 100 miles wide.) But it shouldn't be large enough to cover Las Vegas.